# Any plans for an unified Ubuntu Store?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Right now, there's Ubuntu Software Center on the desktop, Click App Store on mobile, also there's an Ubuntu One Music Store, but no Book store. Is there any long-term plan to get these services unified under one branding and converged on multiple form factors? (Like you have a Google Play Store where you can buy Apps, Books, Music, Movies all under one roof!)
Thank you.